# How perform a query in Cloud Function for Firebase and retrieve a specific attribute

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Cloud Functions and I'm trying to retrieve the attribute 'name' performing a query using its id, but I don't know how to handle the object returned by the query.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.testNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('messages/{email}/{groupChat}/{groupId1}/{groupId2}/{message}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')

    const doc = snap.data()
    console.log(doc)

    const idFrom = doc.idFrom
    const idTo = doc.idTo
    console.log(idTo)
    const contentMessage = doc.content

    /*[...] Some awesome code here not correlated to the question */


    admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('settings')
          .doc('table')
          .collection('room')
          .where('id', '==', idTo)
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot =>{
                console.log('querySnapshot: ' + querySnapshot)
                return null
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error)
          })
          return null
 });
```

I went for the trial & error solution, but the only syntax I tried that returns something rather than 'undefined' or exception, is 'querySnapshot', that logs 'querySnapshot: [object Object]'.

Other useful info: I know that the const 'idTo' is correct and the element searched into the db has both attributes 'id' and 'name'.

What am I doing wrong? Do you have an useful and complete documentation to link to?
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify( querySnapshot.data(), null, 4))`

Comment: Also query snapshot can be array.
`querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to use

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
   console.log(doc.data().name)
})
```

So the final code is:

```
admin
     .firestore()
     .collection('settings')
     .doc('table')
     .collection('room')
     .where('id', '==', idTo)
     .get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
               querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                       console.log(doc.data().name)
                   });
     return null
     })
     .catch(error => {
         console.log('Error sending message:', error)
     })
     return null
```

For more info, check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Comment: Actually, this still is going to have problems, since you're not returning a promise that resolves when all the work is complete.  You're returning just null instead.  If you don't return a promise correctly, there is a chance that Cloud Functions will shut down execution of the code before it's complete, which means your message might not get sent.